# Error al querer obtener el CAE API AFIP SDK y peticion duplicada

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, nextjs

estoy haciendo un sistema de facturacion con next js y node js utilizando a la api afip sdk y estoy teniendo un problema al momento de hacer la peticion para que afip me devuelva el CAE.
Al parecer se esta duplicando la peticion y cuando se ejecuta termina crasheando el servidor. El resultado que arroja por consola es como si creara dos veces la peticion para obtener el CAE( lo crea la funcion createVoucher). A continuacion les muestro mi codigo del lado del front , del servidor y el resultado por consola del lado del servidor
Adjunto el codigo del lado del front end

```html
"use client"
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios'

const page = () => {

  const [cae, setCae] = useState(null);
  const ref = useRef(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const memoizedAxiosPost = useMemo(() => {
      return Axios.post('http://localhost:1234/facturacion', {
        punto_de_venta: 1,
        tipo_de_factura: 6,
        concepto: 1,
        tipo_de_documento: 99,
        numero_de_documento: 0,
        importe_gravado: 100,
        importe_exento_iva: 0,
        importe_iva: 21
      });
    }, []);
  
    if (!ref.current) {
      ref.current = true;
      memoizedAxiosPost.then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setCae(response.data);
        console.log(cae);
      });
    }
  }, []);
 
  return (
    <div>
      {
        <p>{cae}</p>
        
      }
      
      </div>
  )
}

export default page
```

y el codigo del lado del servidor

```html
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const Afip = require('@afipsdk/afip.js');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(
    cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",

    })
)

const afip = new Afip({ CUIT: 20409378472 });
app.post('/facturacion',async (req,res) => {
    const punto_de_venta = req.body.punto_de_venta
    const tipo_de_factura = req.body.tipo_de_factura
    const concepto = req.body.concepto
    const tipo_de_documento = req.body.tipo_de_documento
    const numero_de_documento = req.body.numero_de_documento
    const importe_gravado = req.body.importe_gravado
    const importe_exento_iva = req.body.importe_exento_iva
    const importe_iva = req.body.importe_iva;

    (async () => {
        /**
         * Numero del punto de venta
         **/
        // const punto_de_venta = 1;
    
        /**
         * Tipo de factura
         **/
        // const tipo_de_factura = 6; // 6 = Factura B
        
        /**
         * Número de la ultima Factura B
         **/
        const last_voucher = await afip.ElectronicBilling.getLastVoucher(punto_de_venta, tipo_de_factura);
    
        /**
         * Concepto de la factura
         *
         * Opciones:
         *
         * 1 = Productos 
         * 2 = Servicios 
         * 3 = Productos y Servicios
         **/
        // const concepto = 1;
    
        /**
         * Tipo de documento del comprador
         *
         * Opciones:
         *
         * 80 = CUIT 
         * 86 = CUIL 
         * 96 = DNI
         * 99 = Consumidor Final 
         **/
        // const tipo_de_documento = 99;
    
        /**
         * Numero de documento del comprador (0 para consumidor final)
         **/
        // const numero_de_documento = 0;
    
        /**
         * Numero de factura
         **/
        const numero_de_factura = last_voucher + 1;
    
        /**
         * Fecha de la factura en formato aaaa-mm-dd (hasta 10 dias antes y 10 dias despues)
         **/
        const fecha = new Date(Date.now() - ((new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString().split('T')[0];
    
        /**
         * Importe sujeto al IVA (sin icluir IVA)
         **/
        // const importe_gravado = 100;
    
        /**
         * Importe exento al IVA
         **/
        // const importe_exento_iva = 0;
    
        /**
         * Importe de IVA
         **/
        // const importe_iva = 21;
    
        /**
         * Los siguientes campos solo son obligatorios para los conceptos 2 y 3
         **/
        
        let fecha_servicio_desde = null, fecha_servicio_hasta = null, fecha_vencimiento_pago = null;
        
        if (concepto === 2 || concepto === 3) {
            /**
             * Fecha de inicio de servicio en formato aaaammdd
             **/
            const fecha_servicio_desde = 20191213;
    
            /**
             * Fecha de fin de servicio en formato aaaammdd
             **/
            const fecha_servicio_hasta = 20191213;
    
            /**
             * Fecha de vencimiento del pago en formato aaaammdd
             **/
            const fecha_vencimiento_pago = 20191213;
        }
    
        const data = {
            'CantReg'   : 1, // Cantidad de facturas a registrar
            'PtoVta'    : punto_de_venta,
            'CbteTipo'  : tipo_de_factura, 
            'Concepto'  : concepto,
            'DocTipo'   : tipo_de_documento,
            'DocNro'    : numero_de_documento,
            'CbteDesde' : numero_de_factura,
            'CbteHasta' : numero_de_factura,
            'CbteFch'   : parseInt(fecha.replace(/-/g, '')),    
            'FchServDesde'  : fecha_servicio_desde,
            'FchServHasta'  : fecha_servicio_hasta,
            'FchVtoPago'    : fecha_vencimiento_pago,
            'ImpTotal'  : importe_gravado + importe_iva + importe_exento_iva,
            'ImpTotConc': 0, // Importe neto no gravado
            'ImpNeto'   : importe_gravado,
            'ImpOpEx'   : importe_exento_iva,
            'ImpIVA'    : importe_iva,
            'ImpTrib'   : 0, //Importe total de tributos
            'MonId'     : 'PES', //Tipo de moneda usada en la factura ('PES' = pesos argentinos) 
            'MonCotiz'  : 1, // Cotización de la moneda usada (1 para pesos argentinos)  
            'Iva'       : [ // Alícuotas asociadas a la factura
                {
                    'Id'        : 5, // Id del tipo de IVA (5 = 21%)
                    'BaseImp'   :   importe_gravado,
                    'Importe'   : importe_iva 
                }
            ]
        };
    
        /** 
         * Creamos la Factura 
         **/
        console.log(data)
        const resp = await afip.ElectronicBilling.createVoucher(data);
    
        /**
         * Mostramos por pantalla los datos de la nueva Factura 
         **/
        console.log({
            'cae' : resp.CAE, //CAE asignado a la Factura
            'vencimiento' : resp.CAEFchVto //Fecha de vencimiento del CAE
        });
        res.send(resp.CAE)
    })()
  
})

app.listen(1234, () =>{
    console.log('server is running')
})
```

Y tambien les adjunto que es lo que arroja la consola

```html
server is running
{
  CantReg: 1,
  PtoVta: 1,
  CbteTipo: 6,
  Concepto: 1,
  DocTipo: 99,
  DocNro: 0,
  CbteDesde: 559,
  CbteHasta: 559,
  CbteFch: 20240216,
  FchServDesde: null,
  FchServHasta: null,
  FchVtoPago: null,
  ImpTotal: 121,
  ImpTotConc: 0,
  ImpNeto: 100,
  ImpOpEx: 0,
  ImpIVA: 21,
  ImpTrib: 0,
  MonId: 'PES',
  MonCotiz: 1,
  Iva: [ { Id: 5, BaseImp: 100, Importe: 21 } ]
}
{
  CantReg: 1,
  PtoVta: 1,
  CbteTipo: 6,
  Concepto: 1,
  DocTipo: 99,
  DocNro: 0,
  CbteDesde: 559,
  CbteHasta: 559,
  CbteFch: 20240216,
  FchServDesde: null,
  FchServHasta: null,
  FchVtoPago: null,
  ImpTotal: 121,
  ImpTotConc: 0,
  ImpNeto: 100,
  ImpOpEx: 0,
  ImpIVA: 21,
  ImpTrib: 0,
  MonId: 'PES',
  MonCotiz: 1,
  Iva: [ { Id: 5, BaseImp: 100, Importe: 21 } ]
}
{ cae: '74072149231388', vencimiento: '2024-02-26' }
C:\Users\Gonzaa\Desktop\Prueba_facturador\server\node_modules\@afipsdk\afip.js\src\Class\ElectronicBilling.js:404
                        throw new Error(`(${err.Code}) ${err.Msg}`, err.Code);
                              ^

Error: (10016) El numero o fecha del comprobante no se corresponde con el proximo a autorizar. Consultar metodo FECompUltimoAutorizado.
```

Comment: Hola Gonzalo, el error es de un API de terceros, creo que nom te podemos ayudar ya que solo nos encagramos de preguntas relacionadas a programacion , si bien es programacion, el error es de una api de terceros que solo ellos te pueden decir las caracteriticas del error y que debes hacer

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque trata de resolver un error de un API de terceros